# Parallel SSH connections to remote host with Robot

Tags: robotframework

I have a simple test, using the `SSHLibrary` which I'd like to start and run in parallel on multiple hosts. Now I have statically set 'host1'. **How would I run this on host1, host2 and host3 at the same time?**

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation          Demo
Library                SSHLibrary
Suite Setup            Open Connection And Log In
Suite Teardown         Close All Connections

*** Variables ***
${HOST}                host1
${USERNAME}            user

*** Test Cases ***
Evaluate command status
    [Documentation]    Demo
    ${output}     Execute Command     net show version  
    Should Be True    $output

*** Keywords ***
Open Connection And Log In
   Open Connection          ${HOST}
   Login With Public Key    ${USERNAME}    /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the variable on the command line with the `--variable` or `-V` option:

```
robot --variable host:host1
robot --variable host:host2
```

For more information see [Setting variables in command line](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#setting-variables-in-command-line) in the robot framework user guide.

Robot iteself doesn't provide any features to run tests in parallel. To run them in parallel you could write a script that runs robot in the background for each host, and then combine the reports from each run into a single unified report.

Comment: Would that not still mean that the execution of the tests happens in sequential order? Preferably I'd initiate the test for host1, 2 and 3 at the same time.

Comment: @User: you will have to run robot separately for each host

Comment: Thanks, we were replying at the same time. Follow-up question; would it be possible to provide a minimal example with pabot? I've attempted to get it to work but I can't seem to get the SSH session to build to both hosts simultaneously. Based on the README I'm not entirely sure how to convert the code above to benefit from pabot